# What is the proper way to clean up an open transaction after PersistenceException?

Tags: java, transactions, persistence, openjpa

I'm using OpenJPA 2.0 with a single persistence unit.

In my persistence.xml I have chosen to go with the configuration `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` and manage transactions manually.

Now, in the code below, if a `PersistenceException` gets thrown (and caught), how should I clean up the transaction?

```
    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        MyClassPO myClassPO = (MyClassPO) entityManager
                .createQuery("select bn from myClassPO bn where bn.xxx = :xxx")
                .setParameter("xxx", xxx)
                .getSingleResult();  // NoResultException gets thrown here

        ... do some more stuff ...

        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (PersistenceException e) {

        // what should I do with the open transaction here ??

        logger.error(e);
        throw new MyOtherException(e);
    }
```

I know that the transaction is not getting cleaned up automatically since the next time I run the same operation I get the error message `This operation cannot be performed while a Transaction is active.`

Is it as simple as putting `entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();` in the `catch` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with the following notice:
according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html#rollback%28%29), it could throw an `IllegalStateException`. Also, I suppose you are on the Application Server side, and that's why I would consider the next notice:

Alternatively you could switch back to JTA, manage on your own the JTA transaction with Bean-Managed-Transaction and use the [UserTransaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html)

```
@Resource private UserTransaction userTransaction;
```

Comment: ok, thanks. regarding the `IllegalStateException` - do I need to check if `getTransaction().isActive()` is true before doing the rollback?

Comment: In your example I wouldn't check, as there are really few cases when the transaction could not be active. Maybe I would check if the logic is spitted between different classes (but not your case).